# How to automatically adjust my variables when my component size changes?

Tags: delphi, resize, components, delphi-2009

In my component I need to adjust some variables every time the `Width` or `Height` is changed but before the component is painted. I try to override the `Resize` method and update the variables there but it does not always work. See the code below. If I create the component at run time, everythin it's ok. But if I drop the component on the Form at design time, change its size and run the program, my component is painted at default size because the new size is not updated as it should in `Resize` method. This is also happens when I save the project, close it and reopen it.

```
unit OwnGauge;

interface

uses
   Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, OwnGraphics, Controls, StdCtrls;

type
   TOwnGauge = class(TGraphicControl)
   private
     PaintBmp: TBitmap;
   protected
     procedure Paint; override;
     procedure Resize; override;
   public
     constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
     destructor  Destroy; override;
   end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
 RegisterComponents('OwnMisc', [TOwnGauge]);
end;

constructor TOwnGauge.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 PaintBmp:= nil;
 inherited Create(AOwner);
 PaintBmp:= TBitmap.Create;
 PaintBmp.PixelFormat:= pf24bit;
 Width:= 200;
 Height:= 24;
end;

destructor TOwnGauge.Destroy;
begin
 inherited Destroy;
 PaintBmp.Free;
end;

procedure TOwnGauge.Paint;
begin
 with PaintBmp do begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color:= clRed;
  Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsSolid;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
 end;
 BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height, PaintBmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;

procedure TOwnGauge.Resize;
begin
 PaintBmp.SetSize(Width,Height);
 inherited;
end;

end.
```

Edit:

I've done further research and I found that in `TWinControl.WMSize` handler of WM_SIZE message is the following code:

```
if not (csLoading in ComponentState) then Resize;
```

So now it's clear that `Resize` is not triggered when the values from the designer are loaded.

Comment: Set the bitmap size in constructor as well.

Comment: I tried. It's not working.

Comment: Although probably wrong, I usually adjust the BMP size at the beginning of the `Paint` handler. Of course, check if it's not already the required value first, don't bother assigning if it's already correct.

Comment: @jerry no point checking outside the class because the bitmap class already checks that

Comment: @David Thanks for pointing that out, I figured that might be unnecessary (I don't have access to my IDE at the moment). Curious though, is it wrong to do this in the `Paint` handler as I suspected?

Comment: Do what in the paint handler?

Comment: Yes, if I update the bitmap size in Paint handler it's working perfectly, but I think this is just a good workaround. I  do not understand why it doesn't work in `Resize`, as it should.

Comment: @David Setting the bitmap size, in this case `PaintBmp.SetSize(Width,Height);` as in OP's question.

Comment: @Jerry Here the bitmap serves no purpose. May as well draw direct to the paint canvas. If you want to cache the image and blit it then that should be done outside paint otherwise there would be no benefit.

Comment: I've done further research and it seems that the first time `Resize` is executed, the `Width` and `Height` of the component has default values, not the ones in the designer, so the `PaintBmp` is set to wrong values.

Comment: The changes made in Designer do not trigger a `Resize` with the new values.

Comment: The bitmap seems pointless. Why not remove it and paint direct to the paint canvas.

Comment: In this example it's pointless, indeed. But in my component I need to do something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution !

Instead overriding `Resize` I must override `SetBounds`, because Resize is called from SetBounds, but not when the properties of the component are loaded.

```
procedure TOwnGauge.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
 inherited;
 PaintBmp.SetSize(Width,Height);
end;
```